# Magento 2.2.3 | Cant Find "Search Synonyms" Under Admin->Marketing->SEO & Serch

Tags: magento2

| Summary of the issue
i cant find the "Search Synonyms" in "Admin->Marketing->SEO & Serch"

| Information on your environment
Centos Server | php 7 | mysql 5 | magento 2.2.3 CE upgraded from 2.2.2

| Steps to reproduce
i dont know (:

| Expected and actual results
to be able to show "Search Synonyms" under "Admin->Marketing->SEO & Serch"

Note: i saw some tutorials on youtube like this one: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bE3Gx1P3SvQ"
but i have no idea why it is showing on his screen but not on mine?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is a bug that happens when you have Elasticsearch 5.0+ deployed.
It is fixed in the 2.2.7 release of Magento 2.

Check the release notes (Second point under the Search heading):
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/release-notes/ReleaseNotes2.2.7CE.html